# Lift with Maven and IDEA: Scala plugin can't find dependencies

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, lift

I'm using Intellij IDEA 11, Scala 2.9.1, and Lift 2.4M4.

I've created a Maven module (following the "Using Pure Maven" instructions [here](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Using_IntelliJ_IDEA_to_develop_Lift_applications)) based on the Scala 2.9.1 and Lift 2.4 milestone 4 archetype. I've added Web and Scala facets by hand, and for the Scala facet, I've set the compiler library to point to my (manual) installation of Scala 2.9.1.

I can build the module with Maven, but in the Scala editor, all I see is red -- it doesn't know where to find `sbt`, it doesn't know where to find `net.liftweb`, etc., etc. I've contemplated trying to hack around in my local Maven repository and find the relevant JARs, then add them as ordinary IDEA module dependencies, but given that I'm using Maven in the first place, this seems demented.

Note that I'm pretty experienced with IDEA but [not very experienced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377896/in-idea-is-there-a-way-to-force-reindexing-of-maven-snapshots) using Maven with IDEA, and I'm pretty much a beginner at Scala. What am I supposed to be doing, here?

---

**Note:** I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703115/intellij-idea-doesnt-load-lift-libraries-from-a-sbt-project) but I hope to avoid using `sbt`, even though it's the Scala Way To Do Things, because we've got a giant Java codebase that's only barely converted over from Ant to Maven; a new web framework and new programming language are going to be a tough enough sell already, without having to convince everyone from release engineering up to the VP level we need a new build system as well. What I want is workable Maven builds and pleasant IDEA coding.

---

**Update:** I marked fmpwizard's response below as the answer, because it led me to the actual problem, namely, that the IDEA `.iml` file hadn't picked up any of the dependencies from the POM. That said, I don't think using the IDEA Maven plugin to generate `.iml` files is a sensible solution in 2012. I think IDEA is supposed to do this for you, and I've [filed a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-79682).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That you are using lift is not an issue, try using this [maven plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-idea-plugin/) which will do the manual work of adding dependencies to IDEA.

Comment: That plugin is three years old. Are you saying that even now the only way to work with IDEA and Maven is to use a Maven plugin to externally modify IDEA .iml and .ipr files from the command line?

Comment: FWIW, I tried this anyway, and imported the resulting .iml file (which now has the dependencies), and that seems to have cleaned up most of the problems. I'm marking this as the answer because it led me to the problem of missing dependencies, but I don't think it's right that one should have to do this, and using this plugin isn't a workable long-term solution.